# Specifying primary key with create_column_family

Tags: pycassa

How do you specify a primary key when using pycassa's `SystemManager.create_column_family` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others, you can only (and actually only need to) specify the data type of the primary key, using the key_validation_class parameter.

While CQL lets you specify the name of the primary key column, it's not usable in actual row manipulation.